# Angular ui.scrollpoint prematurely applying ui-scrollpoint class

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

This has been frustrating me for hours – so time to turn to the good people of SO.

In my angular app I am using `ui-scrollpoint` to affix a sidenav once it is scrolled to the top of the screen. It is working as intended when using an absolute scrollpoint value (`ui-scrollpoint="150"`) but not when using a relative value (`ui-scrollpoint="-100"`).

The problem at the moment is that the `ui-scrollpoint` class is applied to the element when the view is loaded (I am using ui-router), even when it shouldn't be.

Even more frustrating is that I haven't been able to recreate the problem in Plunker - [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/PDK6rlZF8kPLk1Rhgt0z) I have mocked the layout of my app - but ui-scrollpoint works as one would expect.

What could be causing this erroneous behaviour? (Documentation is non-existent)

- Does the ui-scrollpoint's parents all need to be `display: block` and
  or `position: absolute`? (Although I've tried this.)
- Does it not work in nested states? (The plunker shows that this is
  ok.)
- Does it not work inside custom and/or transcluded directives. (Again - the plunker shows that this is ok.)
- What styling might be on the various parent elements to make this not work?

The only thing I can think is that the class is set permanently somehow when the directive is compiled before rendering / insertion.

When `ui-scrollpoint=""` or `ui-scrollpoint="0"`, the page renders correctly, but the class gets added as soon as the page is scrolled, even if the element is further down the page.

When `ui-scrollpoint="-100"`, the class is applied from the beginning. It's as if the browser thinks the window has already scrolled past the element.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After no luck recreating the issue on Plunker and trying to find the root cause (which wasn't my custom directives and wasn't my layout), I thought to re-download and install the latest scrollpoint.js.

It is now working. Perhaps a bug in an old version. Perhaps I mistakenly edited my local copy.

Comment: i have a similar issue. Using the latest 2.1.1. Did u do anything else to make this work?